# How to invalidate a file(to be refreshed) served from Cloudfront CDN via Java AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Java SDK to uploaded images to S3, How do I invalidate a file in CloudFront so that it is refetched from s3 origin. How to do it via Java SDK ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CreateInvalidationRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.Paths;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidationBatch;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;

AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials();
AmazonCloudFrontClient client = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(awsCredentials);

Paths invalidation_paths = new Paths().withItems("/path/to/invalidate/foo.jpg", "/path/file2.txt").withQuantity(2);
InvalidationBatch invalidation_batch = new InvalidationBatch(invalidation_paths, "unique_id_like_a_date");
CreateInvalidationRequest invalidation = new CreateInvalidationRequest("distributionID", invalidation_batch);
CreateInvalidationResult ret = client.createInvalidation(invalidation);
```

Note you can only have **three** concurrent invalidations; an invalidation seems to take 10-30 minutes.

Comment: See my answer to invalidation limits.

Answer (score 3):

From AWS Documentation:

You can have invalidation requests for up to 3,000 object URLs per distribution in progress at one time, and each invalidation request can include up to 3,000 object URLs. You can make as many invalidation requests as you want as long as you don't exceed this limit. For example, you can create 30 invalidations that invalidate 100 objects each, but as long as all 30 invalidations are still in progress, you can't create any more invalidations. If you exceed the limit, CloudFront returns an error message.

It usually takes 10 to 15 minutes for CloudFront to complete your invalidation request, depending on the number of object URLs that you included in the request.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Answer (score 3):

With **the new AWS Java SDK 2.x**, I have successfully invalidated some paths with this:

```
        Paths invalidationPaths = Paths.builder()
                .items("/thing.txt", "/foo/bar/*")
                .quantity(2)
                .build();

        InvalidationBatch invalidationBatch = InvalidationBatch.builder()
                .paths(invalidationPaths)
                .callerReference("arcones")
                .build();

        CreateInvalidationRequest createInvalidationRequest = CreateInvalidationRequest.builder()
                .distributionId(distributionID)
                .invalidationBatch(invalidationBatch)
                .build();

        cloudFront.createInvalidation(createInvalidationRequest);
```

Take in mind that the invalidation is asynchronous, so it will be issued to your CloudFront distribution when you run this and will take a while to be processed (you can notice that the invalidation has finished when the status becomes `Completed`).

Answer (score 1):

New update:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CreateInvalidationRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CreateInvalidationResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidationBatch;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.Paths;


// Utils method return AmazonCloudFrontClient
public static AmazonCloudFrontClient getAmazonCloudFront() {
        Regions region = Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1; // Some Region.

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AMAZON_AWS_ID", "AMAZON_AWS_SECRET");
        AWSCredentialsProvider amazonCredentialProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);

        AmazonCloudFrontClient client = (AmazonCloudFrontClient) AmazonCloudFrontClientBuilder //
                .standard() //
                .withCredentials(amazonCredentialProvider) //
                .withRegion(region) //
                .build();
        return client;
}

// Send Invalidation
public static void sendInvalidation(String distributionId, String[] invalidationPaths) {
   
  System.out.println("DistributionID: " + distributionId);
  System.out.println("Send Invalidations: " + invalidationPaths);

  //
  AmazonCloudFrontClient client = getAmazonCloudFront();

  Paths invalidation_paths = new Paths().withItems(invalidationPaths).withQuantity(invalidationPaths.length);
  LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
  // Unique ID like a date: "20201001090000"
  String uniqueId = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
  System.out.println("Invalidation ID: " + uniqueId);

  InvalidationBatch invalidation_batch = new InvalidationBatch(invalidation_paths, uniqueId);
  CreateInvalidationRequest invalidation = new CreateInvalidationRequest(distributionId, invalidation_batch);
  CreateInvalidationResult ret = client.createInvalidation(invalidation);
  System.out.println("Invalidation Result: " + ret);
  System.out.println("Invalidation Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using Object Invalidation, we achieve this.

Object Invalidation - Invalidate objects in a distribution to force CloudFront to fetch the latest object data from the S3 origin.

Please refer this link,
http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html#cloudfront-invalidation