# How to invalidate cache in Cloudfront using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to invalidate cache in AWS cloudfront using the **JAVA SDK** but I am finding it a nightmare to find the relevant information. I already created the project and I am trying to figure out how to use `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClient` to connect to cloudfront and call the invalidate api.

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClient
```

I found an answer to a question similar to mine back in 2016 that recommended the following approach:

```
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials();
AmazonCloudFrontClient client = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(awsCredentials);

Paths invalidation_paths = new Paths().withItems("/path/to/invalidate/foo.jpg", "/path/file2.txt").withQuantity(2);
InvalidationBatch invalidation_batch = new InvalidationBatch(invalidation_paths, "unique_id_like_a_date");
CreateInvalidationRequest invalidation = new CreateInvalidationRequest("distributionID", invalidation_batch);
CreateInvalidationResult ret = client.createInvalidation(invalidation);
```

However some of these classes are now deprecated and/or non-existent anymore.

Can someone please help with the correct way to invoke invalidation API in Cloudfront via JAVA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invalidate a file(to be refreshed) served from Cloudfront CDN via Java AWS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527188/how-to-invalidate-a-fileto-be-refreshed-served-from-cloudfront-cdn-via-java-aw)

Answer (score -1):

I successfully invalidated the cache of certain paths with **AWS Java SDK 2.x** with this:

```
        Paths invalidationPaths = Paths.builder()
                .items("/thing.txt", "/foo/bar/*")
                .quantity(2)
                .build();

        InvalidationBatch invalidationBatch = InvalidationBatch.builder()
                .paths(invalidationPaths)
                .callerReference("arcones")
                .build();

        CreateInvalidationRequest createInvalidationRequest = CreateInvalidationRequest.builder()
                .distributionId(distributionID)
                .invalidationBatch(invalidationBatch)
                .build();

        cloudFront.createInvalidation(createInvalidationRequest);
```

Take in mind that the invalidation is asynchronous, so it will be issued to your CloudFront distribution when you run this and will take a while to be processed (you can notice that the invalidation has finished when the status becomes `Completed`).

Answer (score -3):

[Invalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

To invalidate files, you can specify either the path for individual files or a path that ends with the * wildcard, which might apply to one file or to many, as shown in the following examples:

```
/images/image1.jpg
/images/image*
/images/*
```

Note

If you use the AWS command line interface (CLI) for invalidating files and you specify a path that includes the * wildcard, you must use quotes (") around the path.

For example:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $CDN_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
```

Comment: Thanks mate but I am trying to do this with JAVA.